# TWA: create twa for specific routes

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'd like to create a Trusted Web Application for my website, but I'm interested in doing this for specific routes. For example, I have the following routes:

Login
Signup
Profile
-Dashboard
-Wallet
Payment
-Type
-Invoice
About Us

I want to create a TWA specifically for the following routes:

Login
Signup
Profile
-Dashboard
-Wallet

Is it possible to configure the TWA so that when a user opens it, the login page is automatically displayed?

I've tried configuring my Android project to create a Trusted Web Application (TWA) and specifying the 'login' route as the main entry point. However, when I build and install the TWA, it doesn't open the login page as expected. Instead, it opens the default route of my website. I expected the TWA to launch directly to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i create sub domain and added special route in there